# get the background color of the image view from the grid

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I am trying to implement an app with some gallery view. I have a grid view and the user must be able to select multiple images from the grid, say if the user clicks the first image from the grid (I want to show the user that it is selected..so set a background color for example white), then if the user clicks the same image the background color must be reset to the default one..

How can I  do this...any ideas...

Thanks in advance...

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

use integer and take no%2 if 0 put bg as white if 1 set the value as blue, increment value of the no in each click